# Looking for guidance rewriting specific URL's

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have changed the CMS to my site and it has rewritten the URLs to be more friendly but I have 20 pages which are linked on different sites across the web. I want when people click those old links for them to be redirected to their new respective posts.

I was at first thinking of using a PHP array with a javascript redirect but now I'm thinking .htaccess mod-rewrite would be best.

Whats the best way to have specific URLs redirect to their new URLs?

Answer (score 3):

Use the .htaccess file for redirects. For example:

```
# This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific url
Redirect /index.html http://example.com/location/
```

Add some regex to match your rewrites and send to the dynamically created remote url. For example:

```
# Dynamic redirect
RedirectMatch 301 yourUrl/\(.*)\$ http://external.com/someUrl.html?dynamicVal=$1
```

That would send ...yourUrl/123 -> http://external.com/someUrl.html?dynamicVal=123

Comment: +1 with the note that if these are permanent, be sure to use 301, `Redirect 301 /index.html http://example.com/location/`

Comment: Thanks this looks like it should work but it is not redirecting. This is what my htaccess looks like. I get no errors and no redirects
    
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    //301 Redirect Old File
    Redirect 301 article.php?story=3432442 blog-post.php

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about **URLs on your pages**, then the best way is to edit all such pages with ***current proper URLs***.

If you are talking about **"what to do when someone hits my old URL** (from their bookmarks or by clicking a link on another site, for example) then the best way is to redirect (with code 301) such requests to a new location using Apache's URL Rewrite module.

Example:

```
# Activate Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to another page on the same site
RewriteRule ^mypage.php /other/mypage.php [R=301,L,QSA]

# redirect to another page on ANOTHER site
RewriteRule ^mypage.php http://www.anothersite.com/mypage.php [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Here is the link to [Apache's manual for mod-rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/).

Another useful place -- [Mod_Rewrite Forums](http://forum.modrewrite.com/).

Comment: @LayzOne - So why use Rewrite vs Redirect? Redirecting can be done permanently, but rewriting will need to be done on every hit. Just curious of the pro's of ReWrite vs Redirect. Thx.

Comment: @Twisted In my examples it is actually **redirect** (code 301) -- RewriteRule can do both Redirect and Rewrite. As to why use RewriteRule (from `mod_rewrite`) instead of Redirect/RedirectMatch (from `mod_alias`) -- main reason that you can create redirects that will only occur IF some conditions will be met, which makes it more universal (but if there no such complex requirements (only simple rules) then they both will do the same job).

Answer (score 0):

Apache supports different modules to rewrite/redirect requested URIs:

- [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) with `Alias` and `AliasMatch` for internal rewriting, as well as `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` for external redirecting
- [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) with `RewriteRule` for internal rewriting and external redirecting

The main difference between the mod_alias and mod_rewrite directives is that mod_alias’s `Alias` and `Redirect` directives work with path prefix patterns while the other directives (i.e. `AliasMatch`, `RedirectMatch`, and `RewriteRule`) work with regular expressions.

A path prefix pattern is always always matched when it’s a qualified prefix of the requested path and the remaining path segments are automatically appended to the target path. Here’s an example:

```
Redirect /foo/bar http://other.example/quux
```

If `/foo/bar` is requested, it’s getting redirected to `http://other.example/quux`; likewise `/foo/bar/baz` is getting redirected to `http://other.example/quux/baz`. `Alias` works alike but just internally.

In opposite to that, `AliasMatch`, `RedirectMatch`, and `RewriteRule` work with regular expressions and can be used not just to match path prefixes. Here’s an example:

```
RedirectMatch ^/foo/bar$ http://other.example/quux
```

If `/foo/bar` is requested, it’s getting redirected to `http://other.example/quux` (just like the `Redirect` example above). But if `/foo/bar/quux` is requested, it’s not getting redirected as `^/foo/bar$` doesn’t match `/foo/bar/quux`.

Futher differences between mod_alias and mod_rewrite are that mod_rewrite can also examine other parts of the URI except the path and even HTTP request header fields. It does also allow more complex operations with multiple conditions.